Telomere length and cancer
I've been listening to Bret Weinstein talking about telomere length.
He seems to say that long telomeres provide useful tissue repair capacity when young, at the expense of reduced cancer resistance later in life. The has the evolutionary result that short lived creatures have longer telomeres because they do not live long enough to pay the price of cancer later.
This raised a couple of questions in my mind.

If long telomeres meant higher cancer incidence wouldn't we expect to see more cancer in youth than in old age? As I understand it an individual's telomeres get shorter as time (cell division) progresses.

I thought that cancer had some mutation that produced telomerase and so cancer made its own longer telomeres, regardless of the initial length. I cannot see the connection between initial telomere length and cancer probability.


My own observation, unsullied by rigorous research, suggest that cancer works like a lottery throughout life, the longer you live the more likely you are to get it.

You state: "The has the evolutionary result that short lived creatures have longer telomeres" -  Mr Weinstein, in fact correctly states the opposite.

The risk of cancer increases with age largely because it usually takes multiple mutations in order for a cell line to become cancerous. For example, a cancerous cell might have separate mutations that allow it to evade apoptosis, to repair its telomeres, and to divide rapidly. These mutations can accumulate with age until eventually, a pre-cancerous cell acquires the final mutation that makes it cancerous.

As Jiminy Cricket correctly says above, I got that the wrong way around. This makes a nonsense of my first question and I am sorry to have wasted your time.

Perhaps Eonema answered my second question. Given that cancer requires multiple mutations longer telomeres gives those mutations a better chance to accumulate.

There's also what happens when you run-out of telomere; the chromosome starts to unravel and senescence arrives with an increase in metabolic failure of the tissues concerned.
